# How does Sarah Connor know so much?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, skynet, terminator-genisys

In Terminator Genisys. John Connor says that everything he knows about Skynet and "the future" came from messages from his mother Sarah. So how did Sarah Connor know so much about Skynet and "the future"? And why doesn't anyone else know the things that Sarah Connor knew?

**Note: I don't think this is a spoiler because you learn all this in the first five minutes of the film.**

Comment: Dammit. I've only seen the first four minutes of the movie. Now everything is spoiled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> how did Sarah Connor know so much about Skynet and "the future"?

If you watch the first film, you'll see that

- she learned everything from Kyle Reese, who was sent back in time to protect her when the first terminator was sent back
- she made recordings to give to her son, to explain everything to him

In the second film,

- the Terminator sent back in time to protect John told Sara and John a lot of the history of Skynet. Much of this happens off camera, but is clearly alluded to when Sara asks the Terminator to tell her everything .

> why doesn't anyone else know the things that Sarah Connor knew?

Again, in the first film,

- Reese tried to explain what was going on to the police, but their psychiatrist decided he was crazy and discounted the story.

If you watch the second film, you'll see that

- Sara tried to tell people about the problem, but was found to be clinically insane by the same psychiatrist, and her information ignored

Additionally, there is no evidence that anyone else was ever told about the future.

Comment: Great answer.  I would add that the T-800 in Terminator 2: Judgement Day also told her (and John) a lot about Skynet.  In the Terminator's own words, "I have detailed files".  Sarah's response:  "Tell me everything."  In the first movie, she didn't have much time to talk about it with Kyle, because they were only together for one night, and they spent most of that time running away from the Terminator.

Comment: @WadCheber great point! I'll add that in

Comment: @atk - Happy to be of use.  Again, great answer.  You have my +1

Comment: So, what I'm hearing is... things may have been better for humanity if the Resistance had sent somebody back in time to kill the psychiatrist? :)

Comment: Note that in the SCC the shrink finally came around after seeing the T-1000 squeeze through the bars in T2. I guess watching Arnie take out an entire police station wasn't enough.

Comment: I love his soliloquy in T3 where he talks of how much it scarred him.

Comment: What evidence do we have the events of Terminator 2 occurred at all in the Genisys timeline? My understanding is that it was supposed to be a sequel to T1, not T2. In fact there is some pretty strong evidence T2 never happened, since no reprogrammed Terminators are prepped to travel back with Kyle Reese in the beginning.

Comment: Additionally, the date of Judgement Day is wrong for T2 to have occurred. So, Genisys John could not have learned anything by way of the T-800 sent to protect in him the T2 universe, since it never happened. It has to all be from Kyle.

Comment: @Shamshiel, see the parts of the answer that refer to T1. The answer stands perfectly strongly if the T2 parts did not, in fact, happen.

Comment: @Omegacron: To be fair, Silberman (the psychiatrist) isn't around when the T-800 destroys the police station. We see him walk out the door, yawning and turning off his beeper, just as the T-800 walks in. At the time, Silberman has no idea how lucky he is; it's because he left that he's still alive in Terminator 2.

Comment: @atk: In T2, John also mentions that Sarah would sometimes tell her boyfriends about Skynet and Judgment Day. Understandably, they decided she was crazy and broke up with her soon afterwards.

Comment: @T.J.L.: Fun idea, but it would have made no difference. Nobody but Sarah believes Kyle's story -- not the other police, not Sarah's boyfriends, not even John after Sarah is arrested. Most people who saw the Terminator in action are dead, and the only hard evidence has been hidden away by Cyberdyne Systems. (There are a few exceptions, like the kid who is told by Arnie to get out of the truck, but no one is likely to believe him either.)

Comment: @atk: I agree the answer works with just T1, but my point is it should have only T1. It looks like interviews confirm T2 never happened in any Genisys timeline.

Comment: @Samshiel: True, although the references to T2 explain why no one other than John knows about the future in Genisys. We can assume that "T1 Sarah" (the mother of the John Connor who we see at the beginning of Genisys) tried to convince other people, but was dismissed as crazy and possibly locked up.